# Facing a Curl error when running flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, curl

I am facing a Curl (60) error while running any flutter command: `doctor`, `--version`, or `upgrade`. I am on MacOS Catalina.

Here's the [image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rejb2.png)

Comment: Please write down your error message as a text, not as an image

Comment: Probably your system is lacking valid SSL certs. see a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49044157/969068

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the solution from the Flutter group on Google groups. The problem was that the Curl being used was from my Anaconda distribution, while it should actually have been pointing to `/usr/bin:$PATH`. The solution was to run export `PATH` before running flutter doctor.